# Block click event or ajax requesst if element is clicked frequently in a particular time duration using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an MVC application in which I have some clickable elements which are when clicked ajax request is being sent to the server.

If someone continuously click an element multiple ajax request will be sent. In this case I want to block all other requests and execute only first request and after some time new requests will be sent to server.

How can I do this using javascript or Jquery?

Following is a sample code:

```
<div>
     <input type="button" value="Click" id="btnClick" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnClick").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'someurl',
            success:function(){ alert("Success");},
            error:function(){ alert("Error");}
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can disable element(s) and re-enable it once request is completed. Now, you have to provide relevant code in question itself

Comment: or look at a solution like [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce)

Comment: @A.Wolff : I do not want to disable the element. I have updated the question containing a sample code

Comment: @ArunPJohny : This is exactly what I wanted